# AcroForms in ReportLab not extractable across pages

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab, pypdf, bytesio

I'm trying to add interactive form fields (acroForms) to pdf files of paper based exams to make them usable on computers and tablets. Because most exams already have established layouts, the original must be used as a background, so I'm trying to put interactive fields on top of the original as a second layer of some sort. This works perfectly fine. See code:

```
import io
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas


page_num = 11
file = "input.pdf"
with open(file, "rb") as input_file:
    # read input pdf, grab both target pages, prepare output pdf
    input_pdf = PdfFileReader(input_file)
    page_1 = input_pdf.getPage(page_num - 1)
    page_2 = input_pdf.getPage(page_num)
    output = PdfFileWriter()

    # prepare canvas
    packet = io.BytesIO()
    c = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=A4)

    # put stuff on canvas
    c.drawString(5, 5, "Some Text")
    c.acroForm.textfield(name="Text Field", x=10, y=600)

    # save canvas and text field
    c.save()
    packet.seek(0)

    # grab text to put on page
    text = PdfFileReader(packet)
    page_1.mergePage(text.getPage(0))

    # add first page to output
    output.addPage(page_1)

    # new canvas
    packet = io.BytesIO()
    c = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=A4)

    # put stuff on new canvas
    c.drawString(5, 5, "Some more text")
    c.acroForm.radio(name="Radio", value="1", x=10, y=500)
    c.acroForm.radio(name="Radio", value="2", x=30, y=500)

    # save new canvas
    c.save()
    packet.seek(0)

    # grab text to put on page 2
    text = PdfFileReader(packet)
    page_2.mergePage(text.getPage(0))
    output.addPage(page_2)

    # output to pdf
    with open(f"input-digitised.pdf", "wb") as f:
        output.write(f)
```

Problem arises when I want to read the acroForms with PyPDF2 (also tried other libs with same result). Only fields of either first or second page are detected, depending on which pages fields I filled out first. See code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

pdf = "input-digitised.pdf"

# read pdf
file = PdfFileReader(pdf)

# get all form fields
fields = file.get_fields()

# extract and display all values
values = list(fields.values())
print(values)
```

I already tried using only one canvas instead of two in creation, which leads to the same problem. Saving the pages in separate files works for reading both pages acroForms but I need the pages together. Separating the pages after filling them out, saving them as single pages and reading these single pages for field extraction does not work. Any ideas on where the problem could be?

Comment: Are you naming every field with unique names?

Comment: Yes, as part of the loop in my non-MWE. I also tried different lengths of name strings as someone in a different question suggested that they should not be too long. No difference in my case.